# find what are the objects of dynamic json array?

Tags: php, json, api

while working on one api of travelpayouts, I am facing problem. Objective is to find the top routes from nearest airport. Output is a Dynamic JSON array where the objects changes for every origin location. Here is the one example, popular routes from delhi(DEL)

```
{
 "success":true,
 "data": {  "BLR": {"origin":"DEL",
                   "destination":"BLR",
                   "price":73,
                   "transfers":0,
                   "airline":"9W",
                   "flight_number":809,
                   "departure_at":"2017-01-16T16:25:00Z",
                   "return_at":"2017-01-30T11:25:00Z",
                   "expires_at":"2016-10-11T06:04:57Z"
                  },
            "YTO":{ "origin":"DEL",
                    "destination":"YTO",
                    "price":754,
                    "transfers":1,
                    "airline":"SV",
                    "flight_number":765,
                    "departure_at":"2016-11-04T18:30:00Z",
                    "return_at":"2016-11-11T14:40:00Z",
                    "expires_at":"2016-10-13T06:48:37Z"
                }
    },
"error":null,
"currency":"USD"
}
```

for every origin json data changes, so their objects. so how to extract of this type of json.? Working on PHP.

```
$jsonurl = "URL";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
$json_output = json_decode($json);
$a = $json_output->data->BLR->destination;
echo $a;
```

this gives the value of destination, but problem is that I want to find the destinations.

Comment: Did you give up or what???

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through `data` and get the `destination`:

```
foreach($json_output->data as $obj) {
    echo $obj->destination;
}
```